# RubyCAS with a persistent single ticket & Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, cas

Alright, I'm a huge RubyCAS noob, and this is driving me crazy.

I have installed the `rubycas-client` gem, and have followed along with the official Sinatra setup at [this repo](https://github.com/rubycas/sinatra-cas-client-example). The way this setup is done, every time I request a page, I receive a one-time ticket that's appended to the URL as a query like so:

`http://localhost:9393/?ticket=ST-1373928850`... etc.

If I refresh the page, I get a Sinatra error saying the ticket has already been used up!

I've two questions, then.

1. Is the ticket-per-reload standard behavior?
2. How do I save my CAS login for a session and still retain single sign-out?

#### What I've done:

- I have gone and tried to implement `:sessions` in Sinatra, but this causes single-sign-out to fail.
- I have gone and done my best to follow the steps in the [`rubycas-client` GitHub Repo](https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-client#re-authenticating-on-every-request-ie-the-single-sign-out-problem) (replacing ActiveRecord session storage with Sinatra's `:session` helper).

The RubyCAS documentation for Sinatra is fairly poor, so I'm looking for a definitive answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing the correct thing when you try and reload the page with the same ticket.  That ticket has already been validated.  When you get the validation response you need to then set your own applications cookie or other session option.

I usually add a method that will add a session attribute to the user's cookie like:

```
session["cas"]["username"] = <user from cas validation response>
```

Then in future requests the Sinatra application can protect whatever routes you want with a helper method like:

```
cas = RestClient::Resource.new "#{cas_url}/login", :timeout => 5
checked = cas.get

return true if checked.code == 200
```

In my configure block for Sinatra I do this:

```
 use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => "example.com",:secret => "veryrandomhex"
```

I hope this helps, have any questions let me know.

**UPDATE BELOW**

While discussing this problem, we've uncovered that RubyCas says to not use a regular cookie session for your ruby application in production, while using CAS.  What you'll want to do is:

A. Make sure your cookie expires at the same time or sooner than the CAS cookie

And/Or

B. Make sure your cookie is per browser session, then revalidate the CAS user on next browser session.

For Rack cookie you would specify this extra config for when the cookie is set to expire: `:expire_after => 1440,` (where 1440 is in minutes)

Comment: Dude, thanks a bunch. From my understanding, the `Rack::Session::Cookie` code is not supposed to be used in production. Do you know what would be okay to use in production?

Comment: I don't see anywhere that it says it can't be used in production: http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions or http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Session/Cookie.html (For what it's worth, I've used it on 10-15 applications running in production for 3+ years)

Comment: [This is a file](https://github.com/rubycas/sinatra-cas-client-example/blob/master/lib/cas_example.rb) from the RubyCAS Sinatra example from the creators of RubyCAS. They're using a similar technique with a comment stating that it's not recommended for production. [RackCAS](https://github.com/biola/rack-cas) and RubyCAS implementations both have support for using other forms of session storage, [particularly when using Single Sign-Out](https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-client#re-authenticating-on-every-request-ie-the-single-sign-out-problem).

Comment: Good find, I'm assuming that is based on not expiring the cookie.  However, if you expire the cookie more quickly then the CAS cookie then you can potentially say the user will be logged out of your application before or at the same time as CAS (if that was the first app that authenticated to CAS).  Or you could keep the cookie around for however long the browser session stays open, then on a new session your app can validate the CAS session again.

Comment: Awesome. That would make sense!

Comment: I've accepted your answer. Would you be willing to add some information to your answer concerning this discussion in the comments?

Comment: Hey! I just wanted to know if you had any input on Single Sign Out.

Comment: For when users want to actually sign out, I allow them to click a route like /logout and then the route does this: session.clear - If you are talking about being logged out of CAS first then going to your app, then as long as your app checks during next session it should see that your logged out of CAS.

Comment: Ah. I am looking for a solution to Single Sign Out that could be initiated from another program using CAS. This can't be done with `session`, because the CAS Server can't interact directly with a browser's cookie. I will be engineering a solution with ActiveRecord, and I'll post it here :)

Answer (score 0):

In case of the ruby CAS there are two kinds of session :

(1). The application session.

(2). The Single sign on (SSO) session.

you can use sinatra-session gem for managing the application session and just use session_end! helper method to destroy the application session. For destroying the SSO session unset the session[:cas_ticket] parameter in log out route.

example:

In case of the Sinatra:

```
get '/logout' do 
        session_end!                      # provided by sinatra-session gem
        session[:cas_ticket] = nil        # session variable set by CAS server
      end
```

here we are explicitly setting the session[:cas_ticket] to nil, however you can use *session.clear* in logout route to destroy the current session data .